# Is there a (video-)conferencing tool that supports positional sound (and avatars)?

Tags: audio, video-conferencing

Due to the SARS-CoV-2-pandemic, a lot of companies and institutions are using (video-)conferencing tools for their meetings. One of a problems that I encountered here is that meetings with more than 2-3 people are not really suitable for socializing purposes. The main reason is that, while in real live on a coffee break or evening out with the team you can physically move between smaller subgroups and focus on the conversation there, in a (video-)conference you can't.

I imagine something like Minecraft with positional sound for voice conferencing would be a great step in that direction. Besides the positional sound, having an avatar and the possibility to move around also does a lot. But I could not find a tool with similar features. So my question is, is there a tool supporting such a feature?

I'm not sure if Software Recommendations (moved here from superuser) is the right channel to ask (feel free to move this question / point me to a better place) but the problem should be common at least among many tech firms around the globe, so maybe someone picks up that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Free Software tool [tawk.space](https://github.com/invisible-college/tawk.space/) -
with demo instance at https://tawk.space/ -
claims to offer a cafe like seemless space.

Tawk.space is a frontend which as backend uses cloud-only service Agora.
See their [blog entry](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/implementing-spatial-audio-chat-in-unity-using-agora/) introducing surround support.

Free Software backend [Janus Gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) supports surround audio as well - see their [demo](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/multiopus.html).

Answer (score 0):

wonder.me is close to what you are looking for.  It is not exactly positional sound. You have an avatar in 2D space and can move it around. When you are near other participants’ avatars, a video/audio conference starts seamlessly.
https://www.wonder.me/

Comment: Could you please add some information as to why it is close.